# Python HTTP Requests Lagging by 15 Minutes

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to send a notification every time a new post is made on a given craigslist page. Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
import requests, logging, http.client

http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

url = "https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/cta?query=honda+civic"
page = requests.get(url)
```

If you run this code, you will see this line in the output:
`header: Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 19:31:21 GMT` (obviously with the date and time that *you* run it).

The problem is, if you run the code again, this line doesn't update. You can send as many requests as you want, but it will keep giving you the same stale page for the next 15 minutes. (Notice this line as well: `Cache-Control: max-age=900`  15 minutes=900 seconds) I've tried adding different headers `('user-agent':'Chrome etc', 'Cache-Control':'no-cache',  etc)` but they do nothing. I even tried cycling through a list of proxies to send the requests but I still get stale pages.

When I run the code with the URL set to my own website, it updates on each request. No issues.

Can any web experts out there help me?

Comment: There's a certain amount of caching on the server side that may not be avoidable. If that search string is cached for all users, there's nothing to be done. And anyway: if you're scrape-hammering the site, why should it respond more than once every 15 minutes with fresh data?

Comment: I’m not sure it’s cached for all users… the first response has the exact date & time you send the request. It’s just that it won’t give you a new one for the next 15 minutes. And in the example of looking for an apartment, you won’t get it unless you’re the first in line, hence the need for frequent fresh data